# SQLite cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: sqlite, jsp

I have SQLLite database. Connection for the DB is in SQLite.java class. In ProductPage.jsp I have created an instance of this class.
Mistake is  "SQLite cannot be resolved to a type".  I use Tomcat server. Screen shot is attached. Could you please help me with this?

SQLite.java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

    public class SQLite {
    Connection con =null;

    public static Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            //Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

            //adjust database path
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Lab_4.sqlite");
            System.out.println("Connection successful");
            return cn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

ProductPage.jsp

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Product Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>



         <% Connection cn=new SQLite.getConnection();

            String  pid, name, price, stock, comments;      
            String query = ("SELECT * FROM T_PRODUCT");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);
            //pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); %>

            <table border="2">
       <tr>
            <td>Product ID</td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Product Price</td>
            <td>Product Stock</td>
            <td>Product Comments</td>
       </tr>
       <%  
       try
       {



           while(rs.next())
           {%>

           <tr><td><%out.println(rs.getInt("Prd_ID")); %></td></tr>
           <tr><td><%out.println(rs.getString("Prd _Name")); %></td></tr>
           <tr><td><%out.println(rs.getInt("Prd _Price")); %></td></tr>
           <tr><td><%out.println(rs.getInt("Prd _Stock")); %></td></tr>
           <tr><td><%out.println(rs.getString("Prd _Comments")); %></td></tr>


       <%
           }
       %>
       </table>
       <%
            cn.close();

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
       %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SkUE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try importing the `SQLite.java` class via a `<page>` tag, i.e. add the following to the start of your `ProductPage.jsp`:

```
<%@ page import="SQLite" %>
```

If your `SQLite.java` class actually has a package (which you did not show us), then use this:

```
<%@ page import="package.SQLite" %>
```

Note that many would consider it bad practice to import into a JSP, it being considered a violation of good MVC principles.

Comment: How can I organize this in other way?

Comment: You could just include the connection code directly in your JSP.

Comment: If I add connection code directly in JSP I have to create connection for each query. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and it makes sense to reuse code, but in the case of JSP what I have seen on SO is that page imports are usually frowned upon.